# What is the purpose of using "setVisible" outside the constructor?

Tags: java, user-interface

So, when writing a GUI program my teacher does that:

```
GUIprogram gui = new GUIprogram();
gui.setVisible(true);
```

Why doesn't he put setVisible in method where he creates all GUI stuff (in GUIprogram class)?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you ask your teacher?  It could lead to a great discussion in class.

Comment: @digitaljoel: I am shy, sorry, and I don't see why this question received votes for closing, can you explain, please? Thank you.

Comment: @hey probably because the question appears localized. I think with some edits (rephrasing it for the general case instead of 'my professor) it wouldn't qualify for that anymore.

Comment: @trinithis: Yeah, your argument is amazing, you won. This topic should be closed.

Comment: 3 up votes, 3 down votes, 3 close votes. Don't judge yourself too harshly :) It is much better than -8!

Comment: Compare this with how a "normal" Window/Dialog works: the object is created and *then* shown. There is more flexibility in creating the object first and *then* applying a world-mutating action (perhaps it must be made visible in relation to an event). Some people even argue that *any* mutations/work in a constructor are "bad", but... (this actually goes against a good bit of the Java IO classes ;-)

Comment: @hey: In all seriousness, making the (programmer) user set the visibility makes the code more flexible. For instance, I can create an array of several `GUIprogram`'s, each of which is different. Then I can select one at random and use that one. If each automatically set itself to visible, then too many GUIs will be shown to the (layman) user!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options for turning it on, basically:

1. Turn it on every time in the constructor.
2. Turn it on based on a parameter to the constructor.
3. Turn it on when accessed outside the constructor.

So the mostly likely reason would be that he doesn't want to make it visible every time, and didn't want to make it a parameter to the constructor either. That leaves one option, turning it on afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. What I *do* know...

- That is the way the tutorials (that I have seen) do it.
- That is the way NetBeans does it by default.
- That *may* be the way more programmers are used to it.

The advantage I can think of is that you can build the GUI ahead of time with `new GUIprogram()`. That way, when the time comes to `setVisible` it will be instant. This of course is only useful if your program starts some time before that particular GUI needs to be shown.

Comment: And by "more programmers are" you mean "the teacher is"? Now, how does that start ... "We are the sum [total] of..." ;-)

Comment: Definitely. The teacher is more used to it. (Which could have been because of the tutorials?)

Comment: It is a scarry thought to think a teacher (which might for all we know be an upperclassman or a fresh master's student) is just reading some tutorial online and then teaching the next generation of our coworkers. It makes me wonder how many of my course instructors were doing that too... Although it's conceivable that it seems each new batch of new hires seems to know less than the last because I've learned more and don't remember how little I knew when I was fresh out, so there's definitely a bias there, but it's still a scary thought, considering I bet it happens a lot...